# Why are mobile CSS colors darker than the normal ones?

Tags: feature-request, design

I just noticed that the CSS for mobile has darker colors than the normal one. What is the reason for this? Can it be changed to the same colors?

[image: Desktop]
[image: Mobile]

Answer (score 12):

Mobile CSS is considered legacy at this point, so it doesn't actually inherit perfectly from Stacks. Our long term goal is to kill our mobile views entirely in favor of responsive views. This color difference is design / tech debt. I'm working every day to clean it up, but by the back and forth we've had lately, you can see how complex these things get at our scale

Hopefully it isn't too gnarly to get those colors to be the same.

Comment: Wouldnt time be better spent on the work that needs doing to get to the point we can ditch the mobile view?

Comment: Yes. To be clear, I'm not working to clean up _this_ specific instance of debt that @Dharman has pointed out, but I am indeed chipping away at a lot of things like this.